# HTML Table breaks in everything besides Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, joomla, mozilla

I have written some tables for a joomla article using the standard joomla editor, everything looks fine on Chrome but it goes to hell whenever I open it in Mozilla or Opera. It seems that the table doesnt fit the content field and everything goes way out of it.

http://pastebin.com/QAs8U8Rs

Heres the pastebin with the "code", ive deleted the plain text that is in the h2-s etc...
I know this is definitely not the good way to write it so no need to comment on that. My question is why does it break on everything besides Chrome? Ive added screenshots of the site below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LupIF.jpg

First screenshot is in Mozilla, second one is in Chrome. In Opera it looks the same way as in Mozilla.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/nu/ reveals your problem

Comment: Sorry but care to point out what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, some of those errors are the cause of your problem. A machine can point out where more precisely than I can.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is broken, critically one row has 4 cells in it when your table only has 3 columns.

Obviously Chrome is being a bit more lenient and ignoring some of the issues in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by putting the table inside a div with these attributes:
    div style="display: table; table-layout: fixed;"